# Can I re-enter UK on a 6 month visa a week before it expires having already entered with it once?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-expiration, swazi-citizens

I am a holder of a Swaziland passport. I have a six months UK visa expiring 22 December 2016. I have travelled on it in July this year.

Can I travel to UK a week before my visa expires?

Comment: Assuming your visa is standard multiple entry (i.e. not a single-entry), then there is nothing wrong with that. Do also see http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/51233/32134

Comment: @pnuts ECOs can in special circumstances issue single-entry, but the *standard* standard visitor visa is multiple-entry.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The period of validity is the period over which it may be presented at the border to request entry. It is a multiple entry visa so can be used more than once. It is limited to a stay or stays totalling 6 months so you second visit plus your first cannot exceed that within 12 months.

There is quite a good synopsis at [Breytenbachs](https://www.bic-immigration.com/immigration-news/item/123-rules-of-the-multiple-entry-visitor-visas-to-the-uk/123-rules-of-the-multiple-entry-visitor-visas-to-the-uk):

> **Rules of the Multiple Entry Visitor Visas to the UK**
>
> The visitor visas allow one to travel to the United Kingdom for 6 months out of 12 months. One is only allowed to spend a maximum of 6 months out of 12 months in the UK. Once 6 months in the UK have passed, you will need to leave the UK for 6 months.
>
> The permit holder does not need to return to his/her home country, and are allowed to travel to any other country as long as they are outside the UK.
>
> The visitor visa is multiple entry, which means one do not need to travel and stay for the full 6 months in the UK. For example one can travel for 2 months to the UK and leave for 2 months, travel again for 2 months and leave for 2 month etc., as long as the permit holder does not stay in the UK for more than 6 months per 12 months.