# Can I post date my Visa validity date for the standard visitor Visa of the UK by 3 months?

Tags: visas, uk, applications, visa-expiration

Say that I applied the 6th December 2018, will I be able to post date my Visa validity date to be around 5th March? Because I wish to visit the UK in March and July (the Visa will still be available)

All of this because I have a lot of translated documents that will die by 2019 so I really wish I can submit and get the Visa now for the 5th March then count 6 months so it'll end around the 6th August.

EDIT:
I'm using an invitation from an extended family member, some of my documents ( that have been translated are most likely going to lose their validity IN MY COUNTRY by 2019, I'm a student, I have an exam the 19th December, then itll be the end-of-year holidays, but my uncle that's in te UK told me he'll welcome me only in mid semester vacation (from 14th march to 1st april), I need time to prepare for my exams, 6th is the best I can do for application, It'll add 14 days to 3 months. And I want to travel by 15th March (1 day after mid term vacation start) is this tolerable by the consulate or not?

Comment: So if I want to go to the UK the 15th March to 1st april, I'll be obliged to apply on the gov.uk the 16th of December [and no earlier, if I do: I get an automatic refusal(?)] So that the validity of the Visa starts EXACTLY the 15th March and stays up to 14th of August?

Comment: Sorry, I expanded my comment into an answer, below. No: apply no earlier than 15 December if you're planning to travel on 15 March to 1 April, two weeks. You can apply later, of course. Use the [UK visa processing times tool](https://www.gov.uk/visa-processing-times) to see how long most visas take for applicants in your country. Again, if you say it's a two-week trip, and stay 6 months, that's a problem. (And yes, if you apply more than 3 months in advance, you're told to wait but not refused).

Comment: I'm using an invitation  from an  family member, some of my documents ( that have been translated are most likely going to lose their validity IN MY COUNTRY by 2019, I'm a student, I have an exam the 19th December, then itll be the end-of-year holidays, but my uncle that's in te UK told me he'll welcome me only in mid semester vacation (from 14th march to 1st april), I need time to prepare for my exams, 6th is the best I can do for application, It'll add 14 days to 3 months. And I want to travel by 15th March (1 day after mid term vacation start) is this tolerable by the consulate or not?

Answer (score 3):

A UK standard visitor visa, for which you apply no earlier than 3 months before a planned departure, has a validity period stated on it: it may be 6 months, it could be a number of years, it could be less. A visa validity period and how long you can remain in the UK are not necessarily concurrent.

Applying on December 6 would be 3 months from when you want to enter. If you ask for and are given 6 months, that's how long you can be there, entering on or after the beginning of the visa validity. You would have to exit on or before six months. March 5 to August 5, not 6; it's not counted in days but day of the month from entry. Even after a visa is issued, on arrival at UK immigration control, the leave-to-enter period (how long you can be in the country) may be specified by a border official.

A word of advice: if you ask for a shorter trip in your visa application, enter the UK as planned and then stay for 6 months, you may jeopardise future UK visa applications. UKVI doesn't look kindly when you say one thing and then do another.

Comment: @james smith Your visa validity start date may not be the planned date of travel entered in your application. The last time my partner visited, he applied exactly 3 months in advance, and his visa was dated 9 days earlier than his travel date. The previous visit. he also applied exactly 3 months before and the visa start date was the planned travel date. I mention this because your question states you plan to make a return trip, expecting your visa to end around 6 Aug. The UK visit visa validity is usually 6 months; that doesn’t always mean you can re-enter on a different premise for your trip

Comment: See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51233/can-i-visit-uk-a-month-before-my-visa-expires